# Как сделать поиск по excel файлу с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Имеется форма для поиска

```
<input type="text" id="searchPhrase" />
```

и excel файл (.xls) на сервере. Как при помощи js обратиться к этому файлу и найти совпадения с фразой, заданной в форме?

Comment: Сделайте в JS Ajax запрос на сервер, передав нужную информацию в параметрах запроса. А на сервере организуйте поиск серверными средствами. Возможно, стоит задуматься о переносе данных из Excel в SQL базу данных.

Answer (score 1):

Общий вопрос, общий ответ, нужна библиотека , я выбрал [xlsjs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xlsjs) , из всего что было эта оказалась самая удобная и стабильная, далее делаем серверную часть, например я делал на Node.js, парсим xls , я делал из него JSON. а дальше искал просто с помощью RegEXP и цикла, в принципе файл на 700 строк ищет очень резво даже на CoreDuo 3GHz, вобщем по хорошему тут в двух словах не ответить